# How do I write a JS function that finds an img inside a <li> class and makes that image as a background-image value in the li's css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, function

To explain better.  Imagine this:

```
<li class="whatever">
     <img src="/images/clients/something.jpg">
</li>
<li class="whatever">
     <img src="/images/clients/whatever.png">
</li>
```

Now, I want to write a JS function that will find the `<img>` tag in the `<li>` and will take the src value of the img and make it the background-image or the li class.  If there is a better way to do this, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will help you:

```
var images = $('li > img');
images.each(function(){
    $(this).parent().css('background-image', 'url(' + $(this).attr('src') + ')');
    $(this).hide(); // to hide it
    $(this).remove(); // to remove it from the markup
});
```

Here's your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R5PDJ/

You can also do:

```
$('li > img').each …
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you please provide a fiddle?

Comment: @ariel I've updated the answer. Here's a fiddle that shows it a little better, maybe: http://jsfiddle.net/YY5Cx/

Comment: Thanks!! the thing is that img tag under li then should be hidden.  So how can we do that?

Comment: @ariel I've updated the answer and here's a new jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PQ3ne/

Comment: in addition to background-image how do i add background-size cover to it? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks but i wanted it in the jquery css.  how can we do it in there? thanks!

Comment: You can do it like this: `$(this).parent().css('background-image', 'url(' + $(this).attr('src') + ')').css('background-size', 'cover');`

Comment: that worked but what i amt trying to do is resize image to fit the height and width of the li